# req.isAuthenticated always return false in passport js - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

> When I call req.isAuthenticated() in my local login strategy upon successful login, it always returns true as it should. However, when I try to call req.isAuthenticated in any other file/route in my express server, it always returns false, even when I have a successful login cookie and session. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is?

```
 const express = require('express');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var cors = require('cors');
    const Product = require("./model/ecom");
    const PORT = process.env.PORT;
    const allproducts = require("./controller/allproducts");
    const register = require("./controller/register");
    const passport = require("passport");
    const session = require("express-session");
    const User = require('./model/user');
    const login = require('./controller/login');
    
    
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(cors());
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    
    app.use(session({
      secret: 'My Very First Project In',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie:{ secure :false}
    }));
    
    
    
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    
    
    
    passport.use(User.createStrategy());
    
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
    
    
    app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
// 

> here i have added a console to check what it returns, if register and
> login is working perfectly and cookie is also stored.

    
      console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    
      try {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
          
          const products = await Product.find();
          res.status(200).json(products);
        }
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products from MongoDB:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }
    });
    
    app.post('/form', register);
    
    app.post('/login', login);
    
    app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("server started");
    })
```